# com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: json, android-volley

Everything is working fine but from few hours i am getting the error

```
E/TAG: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I am using `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'` Library

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
Log.e("TAG",message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be Error in your server side where Your API resides.
Check your Rest API working properly.